# Odoo-14: ValueError: Wrong value for ir.actions.report.report_type: 'qweb-pdf'

Tags: python, odoo, qweb, odoo-14

I get this error while trying to install the 'Invoicing' app in odoo-14. It says odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing odoo/addons/product/report/product_reports.xml:4, near

```
<record id="report_product_label" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Product Label (PDF)</field>
    <field name="model">product.product</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">product.report_productlabel</field>
    <field name="report_file">product.report_productlabel</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">'Products Labels - %s' % (object.name)</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="product.model_product_product"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>
```

I'm running Linux mint 20.04 and my python version is 3.6

Comment: Have you tried with latest Odoo source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try to replace**

```
<field name="print_report_name">'Products Labels - %s' % (object.name)</field>
```

**with this line**

```
<field name="print_report_name">'Products Labels - %s' % (object._get_report_base_filename())</field>
```

Comment: <field name="print_report_name">'Products Labels - %s' % (object._get_report_base_filename())</field>